# Zuck.js not loading storys with jQuery get function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get stories from database via PHP and jquery, but the stories don't load.
When i `console.log` the stories then copy and paste directly to Zuck.js data it works.

Like this it doesn't load the stories.

```
$.get( "/php/get_stories.php", function( data ) {
            var currentSkin = getCurrentSkin();
                  var stories = new Zuck('stories', {
                    backNative: true,
                    previousTap: true,
                    skin: 'facesnap',
                    autoFullScreen: currentSkin['params']['autoFullScreen'],
                    avatars: currentSkin['params']['avatars'],
                    paginationArrows: currentSkin['params']['paginationArrows'],
                    list: currentSkin['params']['list'],
                    cubeEffect: currentSkin['params']['cubeEffect'],
                    localStorage: true,
                    stories: [
                        data
                    ]
            });
        });
```

Like this does:

```
$.get( "/php/get_stories.php", function( data ) {
            var currentSkin = getCurrentSkin();
                  var stories = new Zuck('stories', {
                    backNative: true,
                    previousTap: true,
                    skin: 'facesnap',
                    autoFullScreen: currentSkin['params']['autoFullScreen'],
                    avatars: currentSkin['params']['avatars'],
                    paginationArrows: currentSkin['params']['paginationArrows'],
                    list: currentSkin['params']['list'],
                    cubeEffect: currentSkin['params']['cubeEffect'],
                    localStorage: true,
                    stories: [
                        Zuck.buildTimelineItem(
                "smokzz", 
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fanpage-cloud.appspot.com/o/images%2F400x400_15875784403142B36219B-C4E2-4785-85B8-6DE86731F1EC.jpeg?alt=media&amp;token=32af1fc6-0851-4abf-91d1-140d3041a5c1",
                "smokzz",
                "",
                1610232198,
                [
                  ["ramon-2", "video", 0, "", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramon82/assets/master/zuck.js/stories/2.jpg", false, false, 1610232198],
                ]
            ),Zuck.buildTimelineItem(
                "smokzz", 
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fanpage-cloud.appspot.com/o/images%2F400x400_15875784403142B36219B-C4E2-4785-85B8-6DE86731F1EC.jpeg?alt=media&amp;token=32af1fc6-0851-4abf-91d1-140d3041a5c1",
                "smokzz",
                "",
                1610232198,
                [
                  ["ramon-2", "video", 0, "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fanpage-cloud.appspot.com/o/images%2F1602766148481trim.F3B26A23-455F-49DD-8B97-430BBB4DF57C.MOV?alt=media&token=0be5cbfd-828b-46dc-87c3-3fc6311db14d", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramon82/assets/master/zuck.js/stories/2.jpg", false, false, 1610232198],
                ]
            ),
                    ]
            });
        });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once('init.php');
$db = new User();
        foreach ($db->get_stories() as $row) {
            echo 'Zuck.buildTimelineItem(
                "'.$db->get_user_full_name($row['user_id']).'", 
                "'.$db->getProfileImg($row['user_id']).'",
                "'.$db->get_user_full_name($row['user_id']).'",
                "",
                '.time().',
                [
                  ["ramon-2", "video", 0, "", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramon82/assets/master/zuck.js/stories/2.jpg", false, false, '.time().'],
                ]
            ),';
        }


?>
```

First data of php are getting from Mysql Database the second one is just for a test.
I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example where you copy-pasted them, you're calling a function on each story. Assuming that data is the same shape, you'll want to do this:

```
stories: data.map(function (story) { return Zuck.buildTimelineItem(story) }),
```

Comment: im getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function`

Comment: Then I guess the data you're getting back from the API is not an array. Could you update your question with a copy-paste of what comes from the API? I can update my answer to work for its format.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem then. Your API is returning stringified JS. There are two ways you could fix this: the dangerous way (using `eval`) and changing the API to send back JSON data rather than stringified JS.

Comment: I would open a new question or search around about how to build JSON data in PHP and return that to the client — I'm not good enough at PHP to take a stab at it. Alternatively you could use `eval(data)`, but that is generally not recommended.

Comment: You mean using eval(data) on javascript function or at PHP

Comment: On the JavaScript side. Your PHP code is returning stringified JavaScript rather than JSON data (or XML, etc.), which means your client would need to `eval`()` it. `eval` is considered to be a bad practice though, so the "correct" way to fix the issue would be to have the PHP server return JSON.

Comment: Yes i understand that but when i use `eval(data)` i get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`